# Iterating through all combinations of categorical variables in stripplot

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

for i in data:
   for j in data:
      for k in data:
         sns.stripplot(data=data1, x=i, y=j, hue=k) 
         plt.show()
```

I am trying to create every possible combination of stripplot between the variables in data1.
Is there a compact way to do this?
And since plt.show() displays each output in a separate window, is it possible to save the output as pdf/png or make the output display in a single window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import itertools

# Create list of column names
cols = list(data1.columns)

# Create all possible combinations for x, y, and hue
combinations = list(itertools.product(cols, repeat=3))

# Number of plots
n = len(combinations)

# Create a grid of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(n**0.5), int(n**0.5), figsize=(15, 15))

axs = axs.flatten()  # Make it 1D for easy iteration

# Create plots
for ax, (i, j, k) in zip(axs, combinations):
    sns.stripplot(data=data1, x=i, y=j, hue=k, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f"x: {i}, y: {j}, hue: {k}")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("all_combinations.png")
plt.show()
```